# Unmet dependencies (linux-headers, linux-image)

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

I am trying to install  *a program*  on my Linux.
When running: `sudo apt-get install nams` I keep getting:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
         linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic :   
          Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic but it is not going to be installed
         linux-image-generic :  
          Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried to fix it doing:  `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: The install command is : `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nams` ....

Comment: I've tried that, but the Error that I get is:  Unable to locate package nams

Comment: try `sudo apt-get upgrade -f` to upgrade packages and fix broken dependencies, or you can manually install the missing dependancy `sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic`

Comment: »» apt-get install nams ««  What is `nams` supposed to do ? "nams" is an unknown name / unknown application. Do you mean `nam` ?

Comment: @KnudLarsen sorry, it is NASM (Netwide Assembler)

Answer (score 6):

Seems like you have double sources in your plist.

To fix this issue:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Then run :

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Also you can comment out the double source in the sources.list

If you need help, print the output of the sources.list and show me.

Like this :

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list > /home/user/sources.txt
```

If you wanne do it yourself just use nano or vim :

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue and this fixed it for me!