# Unmet Dependencies for zsnes (works on one computer but not my other)

Tags: apt, dependencies

When I try (On Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS)

```
sudo apt install zsnes
```

I get the following

```
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming. 
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
    
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    zsnes:i386 : Depends: libsdl1.2debian:i386 (>= 1.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
```

I then try

```
sudo apt install libsdl1.2debian:i386
```

I get the following

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    kio : Depends: libkf5notifications5 (>= 4.96.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libkf5wallet-bin but it is not going to be installed
    libkf5wallet5 : Depends: libkwalletbackend5-5 (= 5.44.0-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
    libsdl1.2debian:i386 : Depends: libcaca0:i386 (>= 0.99.beta17-1) but it is not going to be installed
```

I keep going down the rabbit hole of trying to install the these unmet dependencies and I am just totally in over my head. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have 2 linux machines at home (2 laptops). One laptop has no problem installing zsnes but my other laptop just keeps giving me errors. Both my laptops are running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS so I don't understand why one computer with the same OS has no issue installing a program and the other one does.

I tried the solution in here and it did not work [Unmet dependencies (linux-headers, linux-image)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904319/unmet-dependencies-linux-headers-linux-image)

I've tried

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

and that did not fix the problem. I've also already run

```
sudo apt update
```

and

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

and yes even

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt -f install
```

and still the same issue. When I run

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I get this

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe multiverse main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
```

Comment: What are you apt repos?

Comment: deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe multiverse main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main

Comment: I added the following to my sources.list ran an update then upgrade and it worked. Thanks. 

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe multiverse main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main universe restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main multiverse universe restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse

Comment: That's a more complex way of solving my problem but basically yes. I answered my own question below once Ray made me look at my sources.list file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Ray Wu](https://askubuntu.com/users/946331/ray-wu) for asking me what my sources.list file had. Originally it only had the following sources.

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe multiverse main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
```

I then checked my other computer and made my sources.list file look like this.

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe multiverse main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main universe restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main multiverse universe restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

I then ran an update and an upgrade and now zsnes installs with no issues. Thanks!!!